# No such entity with cartId = 148478627

Tags: magento2

I am getting the following error on stage site when I try to place order using check/money order.

The order gets placed but the user doesn't get redirected to success page.

It throws following error

[image]

Comment: Are you facing this issue on cart page as well ? like 
www.yoursite.com/checkout/cart

Comment: No only on checkout page